# How to combine angular fire guards?

Tags: angularfire2, angular-router-guards

The AngularFire auth guard [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md) shows different ways to allow authentication.

Only admin users:

```
const editorOnly = pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.role === "editor"));
```

Self only:

```
const onlyAllowSelf = (next) => map(user => !!user && next.params.userId === user.uid);
```

My question, is how to combine the two that *either* an editor/admin *or* the user himself can open the component.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `combineAuthPipes` function, which uses `forkJoin` under the covers:

```js
const combineAuthPipes = (authPipes: AuthPipe[]) => 
    switchMap((t: Observable<firebase.User>) => forkJoin(authPipes.map(x => x(t))))

const loggedInThenRedirect = pipe(
    map((t: firebase.User) => of(t)),
    combineAuthPipes([
        loggedIn,
        customClaims as AuthPipe,
        hasCustomClaim('admin'),
        hasCustomClaim('editor')
    ]),
    map(([isLoggedIn, customClaimList, admin, moderator]) => {
        return {
            loggedIn: isLoggedIn,
            customClaims: customClaimList,
            admin, 
            moderator
        }
    }),
    map((t) => {
        if (t.admin) {
            return true
        }
        if (!t.loggedIn) {
            return ['login']
        }
        return ['unauthorized']
    })
)
```

Use like this:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', component: SomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [
            AngularFireAuthGuard
        ],
        data: { authGuardPipe: () => loggedInThenRedirect }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as your final function adheres to the `AuthPipe` interface (mapping `Observable<firebase.User | null>` to `Observable<boolean | string | string[]>`) you can compose any custom pipe.

The solution I went for used:

1. `pipe` operator to pipe into the final `AuthPipe` interface.
2. `forkJoin` to join together the results from multiple `AngularFireAuth` pipes.
3. `map` to convert the intermediary results to `boolean | string | string[]`.

With this approach you can use the results of multiple `AuthPipe`s when implementing `canActivate` logic.

(essentially a cleaner version of @pixelbits answer)

```js
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, AuthPipe, emailVerified, loggedIn } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth-guard';
import { forkJoin, of, pipe } from 'rxjs';

const combined: AuthPipe = pipe(
  mergeMap((user) => forkJoin([loggedIn(of(user)), emailVerified(of(user))])),
  map(([isLoggedIn, isEmailVerified]) => {
    console.log({ isLoggedIn, isEmailVerified });
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return '/auth/login';
    }
    if (!isEmailVerified) {
      return '/auth/verify-email';
    }
    return true;
  }),
);

// usage
{
   component: MyComponent,
   canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
   data: { authGuardPipe: () => combined },
},
```

A note on the `customClaims` `AuthPipe`: it expects `firebase.User` (does not allow for `null`), so you can either:

1. Use a ternary operator: `user ? customClaims(of(user)) : of(null)` or
2. Call anyways `customClaims(of(user as any))`, which returns an empty array when user is null ([source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/5ecf8757d5ea5cbd93e0c0881a95deea9f0310e3/src/auth-guard/auth-guard.ts#L47))

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it to work, but perhaps there is a more eloquent answer:

```js
const selfOrAdmin: AuthPipeGenerator = next => (users$) =>
  combineLatest([customClaims(users$).pipe(map(claims => claims['role'] === 'editor')),
    users$.pipe(map(user => !!user && next.params.userId === user.uid))])
  .pipe(map(([isAdmin, isSelf]) => isAdmin || isSelf))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Went with Michael Kang's answer, but I had to change

```html
const combineAuthPipes = (authPipes: AuthPipe[]) =>
  switchMap((t: Observable<firebase.User>) => forkJoin(authPipes.map(x => x(t))))
```

to

```html
const combineAuthPipes = (authPipes: AuthPipe[]) =>
  switchMap((t: User | null) => forkJoin(authPipes.map(x => x(of(t)))))
```

Otherwise I would get

Unable to lift unknown Observable type errors in the console.